# Unable to deploy Firebase function due to TS config

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, tsconfig

Unable to deploy the firebase function with the same code as previous deployment.

I am receiving TS errors:

```
functions: updating Node.js 16 function stravaSubscription(us-central1)...
Build failed: \> build \> rimraf lib && tsc

error TS5083: Cannot read file '/tsconfig.json'.
src/firebase/activities.ts(9,8): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../common/models/activity' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/firebase/activities.ts(10,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../common/models/user' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/firebase/activities.ts(14,8): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../common/utils' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/firebase/activities.ts(117,30): error TS7006: Parameter 'v' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/firebase/activities.ts(117,33): error TS7006: Parameter 'index' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/firebase/activities.ts(121,34): error TS7006: Parameter 'time' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/firebase/activities.ts(121,40): error TS7006: Parameter 'index' implicitly has an 'any' type.
src/firebase/goals.ts(5,8): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../common/models/user' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/strava/methods/subscriptionPost.ts(3,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../common/models/user' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/strava/methods/subscriptionPost.ts(17,8): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../common/utils' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/strava/services/activities.ts(7,8): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../common/models/activity' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/strava/services/auth.ts(5,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../common/models/token' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/strava/services/auth.ts(6,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../../common/models/user' or its corresponding type declarations.; Error ID: 1a2262f3

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions: stravaSubscription(us-central1)
```

Nothing has changed, I tried reinstalling npm, updating as well but no luck.
It runs fine using the emulator, no errors if I build or use lint.

I tried reverting my changes from the common folder to have everything in the functions/src
Common folder are just interfaces used by the frontend and backend.

I still get `error TS5083: Cannot read file '/tsconfig.json'` with all in src.

Comment: Please edit the question to show enough detail that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.  It would be helpful if you start a new, working project from scratch and explain *minimally* what you add to it that causes the issue.